# jQuery window resize on tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs, resize, window-resize

I've got a masonry image grid within 2 tabs (so 1 masonry grid within each tab content area). The common issue i'm having is switching between tabs is messing up the grid because of a window resize issue.

You can see working example here: http://www.gomy5.co.uk/our-work-copy/

I'm currently trying .resize on tab click, but it's not working correctly.

```
$(".tab-link").click(function(){
    $('#tab-1').resize();
    $('#tab-2').resize();
});
```

Any ideas why it's not re-sizing the tabbed content area correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Could you expand on the problem? In Chrome, I just see the Masonary expanding past its container.

Comment: On the first tab (the open one on page load). The tab is open on load the masonry container can calculate height and display accordingly. But on the second tab (the closed/hidden one) because it's not active on page load it's not getting the dimensions of hidden elements and setting the height. So when you click on the tab it's still got the masonry container height set to 0. I believe this is a common problem when hiding / show dynamically generated content in tabs - and the resize function needs triggering upon displaying the hidden content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a working jQuery solution. So i've found a css based one. Instead of using

```
display:none
```

and the dimensions not being set on hidden elements. I changed and used

```
visibility:hidden;
visibility: visible;
```

This seems to have solved the problem.